# How do I read keystrokes from a USB keyboard?

Tags: python, usb, pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 32 bit running bullseye.  It runs headless but with a usb mouse.  In python code I want to read key presses from a USB keyboard.  I have tried the python keyboard module but that only works if I run the code as root, which I don't want to do.
I have seen a lot of posts talking about /dev/ttyUSB  just /dev/tty0 to 63
How can I get the key presses?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use (if you are using pygame) this:

```
import pygame

player_x = 100
player_y = 100
player_width = 50
player_height = 50
player_speed = 5

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False

keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and player_x > 0:
    player_x -= player_speed
if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and player_x < width - player_width:
    player_x += player_speed
if keys[pygame.K_UP] and player_y > 0:
    player_y -= player_speed
if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and player_y < height - player_height:
    player_y += player_speed
```

Comment: I tried pygame but that needs a console and I don't have one.

Comment: What do you mean console? Pygame works on keyboard, so what do you mean by console?

Comment: I tried with pygame and it errored.  One of the error messages said that it could not find console, I believe that it needs X-Console installed.  I have now found a solution using evdev and subprocess.